# R: getting rid of for loop and speeding code

Tags: r, performance, loops, matrix

I would like to speed up my calculations and obtain results without using loop in function `m`. Reproducible example:

```
N <- 2500
n <- 500
r <- replicate(1000, sample(N, n))

m <- function(r, N) {
  ic <- matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = N)
  for (i in 1:ncol(r)) { 
    p <- r[, i]
    ic[p, p] <- ic[p, p] + 1
  }
  ic
}

system.time(ic <- m(r, N))
#  user  system elapsed 
#  6.25    0.51    6.76 
isSymmetric(ic)
# [1] TRUE
```

In every iteration of `for` loop we are dealing with matrix not vector, so how this could be Vectorized?

@joel.wilson The purpose of this function is to calculate pairwise frequencies of elements. So afterwards we could estimate pairwise inclusion probabilities.

Thanks to @Khashaa and @alexis_laz. Benchmarks:

```
> require(rbenchmark)
> benchmark(m(r, N),
+           m1(r, N),
+           mvec(r, N),
+           alexis(r, N),
+           replications = 10, order = "elapsed")
          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
4 alexis(r, N)           10    4.73    1.000      4.63     0.11         NA        NA
3   mvec(r, N)           10    5.36    1.133      5.18     0.18         NA        NA
2     m1(r, N)           10    5.48    1.159      5.29     0.19         NA        NA
1      m(r, N)           10   61.41   12.983     60.43     0.90         NA        NA
```

Comment: what is the core purpose of the function? could you explain that !

Comment: A matrix is just vector with dimensions.

Comment: If speed is your concern, then you should consider using the apply functions.

Comment: @Ansjovis86 Why that ? he's not growing anything inside the loop here, not sure the overhead of *apply would help (there's even a chance it will be slower).

Comment: Well, I did spend a few minutes trying to understand the overall process, and it's highly unclear for me.

Comment: @Tensibai
Assume we want to estimate pairwise inclusion probabilities by simulations. We have population with N units, and we draw sample of length n. In matrix r, each column represent indexes of one sample.
Then function m for each sample (column of r) adds +1 where bouth i-th and j-th elements are in this sample. Resulting matrix contains numbers of times that both i-th and j-th elements are in samples, corresponding to matrixes [i, j] element. I hope that I made things clearer.

Comment: Can't `table` give you expected results ?  (probably not, but this is out of my scope of knowledge)

Comment: @Tensibai I have looked on `table`, but I haven’t found a way to use it in this case. Maybe I have overlooked something.

Comment: Your operation seems similar to `tcrossprod(table(r, col(r)))`. Or, its faster version `tcrossprod(array(tabulate(r + (col(r) - 1L) * N, N * ncol(r)), c(N, ncol(r))))` which is a similar approach to those of @Khashaa

Comment: @alexis_laz Thanks, I am adding your suggestion to benchmarks, as it slightly increases performance. Too bad that your approach is harder to intuitively understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be significantly faster as it avoids operations on double indexing

```
m1 <- function(r, N) {
  ic <- matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol=ncol(r))
  for (i in 1:ncol(r)) { 
    p <- r[, i]
    ic[, i][p] <- 1
  }
  tcrossprod(ic)
}

system.time(ic1 <- m1(r, N))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.53    0.01    0.55  

all.equal(ic, ic1)
# [1] TRUE
```

Simple "counting/adding" operations can almost always be vectorized

```
mvec <- function(r, N) {
  ic <- matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol=ncol(r))
  i <- rep(1:ncol(r), each=nrow(r))
  ic[cbind(as.vector(r), i)] <- 1
  tcrossprod(ic)
}
```

Comment: Great, more then 10x faster! Thank you. But I still wonder, could we do this without loop?

Comment: Thank you! Could you add your first function (with loop) to answer ass well, so I can add some benchmarks for all 3 functions.